# pg_restore using azure platform

Tags: postgresql, azure, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore a postgres dump on Azure.

Most of the restore are doing ok, one issue is giving me some headache: the `postgres` role.

In most postgres database, the postgres role is set as super user by default.

In Azure, the postgres role is set as a normal role without super user privilege.

I'm using this command line to restore to the database on Azure

```
pg_restore -x --host dwwhatever.postgres.database.azure.com --port 5432 --username "avocado@dwwhatever" --dbname "BI_DB" --no-password --verbose "C:\Users\andyk\Desktop\report.backup"
```

The `-x` known as `--no-acl` should allow me to not have any roles granting but it does not work.

I have this instead.

[image]

I tried to grant the only "superuser" role available in Azure, `azure_pg_admin`, to the `postgres` role but it did not help either.

Any tips are more than welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, my name is Satya, and I work in Azure Databases for PostgreSQL. For me to better understand the question could you please provide the following info to my emai? snarlap at Microsoft dot com                                    1. With what credentials pg_dump is taking on the source server? 2. Is "Postgres" user superuser on source?

Comment: Also please make sure you set --no-owner option while restoring the dump. You can also use this option when taking the dump  if it is going to be in the plain text format.

Comment: hi @Satya_MSFT, I will email you right now with all the details